# Returning on-the-fly relationship in graph form in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm pretty new to Neo4j and graph DBs in general, and have been playing around with it for the last few days. I've now hit something I'm stumped on: I'm trying to create a "temporary" relationship between two disjoint nodes just for the sake of a RETURN, then not store this relationship within the DB afterwards.

The dataset I'm using is a graph of Movie and Person nodes provided in one of the basic Neo4j built-in tutorials. My query is currently as follows:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r1:ACTED_IN]-(m1:Movie)-[r2:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.name="Kevin Bacon"
RETURN {start:p1,rel:"COSTAR",end:p2}
```

What I'd ultimately like to see is a central "Kevin Bacon" node with COSTAR relationships to a series of Person nodes around it, without any Movie nodes or ACTED_IN relationships being displayed. The query above *does* show the COSTAR relationship in the returned rows, but it *does not* appear on the graph itself; I've attached a few screenshots of what I'm seeing.

The only other idea I have is to use the MERGE keyword to create a COSTAR relationship, but (as I understand it) this actually stores the relationship in the DB which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: "Graph result, note that COSTAR is *not* present]

[image: "Rows" result, note that COSTAR is present]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neo4j Browser only visualizes nodes and relationships that actually exist in the DB. So, there is no way to do what you want without actually creating the `COSTAR` relationships, visualizing the result in the Browser, and then deleting all the `COSTAR` relationships.

As a workaround you could simply display the nodes of all of Kevin Bacon's costars, like this:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Movie)-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.name="Kevin Bacon"
RETURN DISTINCT p2;
```

Comment: I see. I think for now I'll just go with returning just the co-stars, rather than creating-then-later-deleting a relationship since that seems messy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So you want the relationships to appear in the graph visualization in the Neo4j browser but not store these relationships in the graph itself? I can't think of a way to make that happen (without hacking it), but would deleting the relationships after you are done generating the visual work?

Query to create `COSTAR` relationships:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r1:ACTED_IN]-(m1:Movie)-[r2:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.name="Kevin Bacon"
CREATE UNIQUE (p1)<-[:COSTAR]-(p2);
```

Execute your query to populate the graph in Neo4j Browser...

Then to delete the `COSTAR` relationships:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[r:COSTAR]-(:Person)
DELETE r;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this (now... 6 years later) is with the gds.graph.create.* functions (assuming you load GDS)
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-create/

With a graph as simple as this, gds.graph.create(...) would be enough (creating COSTAR for all co-starrings)

Or, if you wanted to do some constraining, gds.graph.create.cypher(...)

The in-memory graph projection feels like what you wanted to achieve - it persists only as long as the DBMS is active, or until you call gds.graph.drop(...)